# redux-form with typescript generates the exception : ''Property 'createFunction' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.''

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux-form

I am trying to create a form redux-form 6.6.3 using typescript 2.3 and react. I have installed types definition @types/redux-form 6.6.2. Here is the form:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { reduxForm, Field } from 'redux-form';
import styles from '../../styles/styles';

class CreateFunction extends React.Component < any, any > {
  private required = (value) => (value == null ? 'required' : undefined);

 private handleSubmit = () =>{}

  public render() {

    return (
      <div style={{ marginTop: 30 }}>    
         <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <Field name="name" component="input"
            hintText="Veuillez saisir la fonction"
            floatingLabelText="Fonction"
            style={styles.textField}
            validate={this.required}
            />    
          </form>    
      </div>
    );
  }
}    
const createFunction = reduxForm({
  form: 'createFunctionForm',
})(CreateFunction);

export default createFunction;
```

But once the CreateFunction imported like this:

```
import createFunction from '../../functions/containers/functiolList';
```

and used like this:

```
 <createFunction />
```

I can't build and I've got this error message:

```
severity: 'Error'
message: 'Property 'createFunction' does not exist on type 'JSX.IntrinsicElements'.'
at: '66,9'
source: 'ts'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to import it having its name starting with [capital letter](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#user-defined-components-must-be-capitalized):

```
import CreateFunction from '../../functions/containers/functiolList';
```

then later:

```
<CreateFunction/>
```

If you refer to your custom component starting with lowercase letter - it will be treated as one of built in ones and not your custom.

Comment: Thank you! You really help me.